# Getting Conversion Problem of Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 33

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
MonthFormate time
    Apr-18  14.53
    May-18  1.78
    Jun-18  7.33
    Jul-18  10.00
    Aug-18  46.76
    Sept-18 23.64
    Oct-18  41.34
    Nov-18  NULL
    Dec-18  NULL
    Jan-19  134.80
    Feb-19  1.69
    Mar-19  98.06
```

Getting current Year

```
 select *
 from #ResultData 
 WHERE YEAR(CONVERT(date, '01-' + Monthformat)) = YEAR(GETDATE()) - 1;
```

Getting previous Year

```
select *
from #ResultData 
WHERE YEAR(CONVERT(DATE, '01-' + Monthformat)) = YEAR(GETDATE()) 
  AND MONTH(CONVERT(DATE, '01-' + Monthformat)) <= MONTH(GETDATE());
```

Comment: What's your expect result ?

Comment: Get Current Year Jan-19 to Mar-19 and 2nd query for Apr-18 to Dec-18

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, how about using strings instead?

```
select rd.*
from #ResultData rd
where '20' + right(monthformat, 2) = datename(year, getdate())
```

and for the previous year:

```
where '20' + right(monthformat, 2) = datename(year, dateadd(year, -1, getdate()))
```

This assumes are dates are since 2000.  If not, you can add additional logic to handle earlier dates.